# Using VBA, how do I select cells in a column until I hit a set string

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and am looking to write a dynamic VBA macro to start in a specified column, and highlight each cell in that column incrementally until I reach a cell containing the word "NULL". I don't however want to select the cell containing "NULL".

Is there any anyone that could provide a simple to follow VBA script to do this?

Lets say my data is on day 1:

```
ColumnHeading
123   
NULL
```

And then on day 2:

```
ColumnHeading
123
13
16
NULL
```

Comment: use `Find("NULL", lookin:=xlValues)`

Comment: I have 16 different columns, all with different data in. I need to amend the format of a few, with different formats. Will this method select EVERY instance of NULL or just for that column?

Comment: Add a loop `For Col = StartCol to LastCol`, and then search for "NULL" per column (with answer gave from Batman, aka @BruceWayne)

Comment: see my edited answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the below should work. If you have "Null" many times in a column, you'll need to tweak a little, as I mention.

```
Sub t2()
Dim nullCell As Range
Set nullCell = Columns("A").Find(what:="Null")
Debug.Print nullCell.Address

'If "Null" can appear many times, and the cell with the highest row number is the one you want, use this (uncomment out to use):
'Set nullCell = Columns("A").Find(what:="Null", Searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
'Debug.Print nullCell.Address

End Sub
```

(Assumes your column A has the list)

Comment: This seems to give me what I wanted. Thanks for the different ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this coding in workbook open events

```
dim I as integer
I=sheet1.range("A").end(xldown).row

sheet1.range("A"&i+1).value="NULL"
```

Comment: I don't think OP wants to add "Null", but rather find that string in a column/list. (Although his examples seem to show that "Null" is always at the end, in which case perhaps he could just use your `l` and his cell is `Cells(l,1)` if column A is the one with the list).

Comment: Yes, the last piece of data is always NULL

Comment: So finding the cell with NULL is one thing, selecting the cells up to the one preceding it is another... Is this an easy task?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through all Columns with Data, and per Column will search the row where "**NULL**" is found, and then set `Rng` for the current Column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindNull()

Dim LastColumn          As Long
Dim Col                 As Long
Dim NullCell            As Range
Dim Rng                 As Range

' modify to your sheet name
With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' let's say your data starts from row 2
    LastColumn = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    ' starting from Col "A" >> modify to your start Column
    For Col = 1 To LastColumn
        Set NullCell = Columns(Col).Find(what:="Null")

        ' for debug : print address of "NULL" and Row (per Column)
        Debug.Print NullCell.Address & " ; " & NullCell.Row

        ' set Rng for Curren Column
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, Col), Cells(NullCell.Row - 1, Col))

        ' for debug : print address current's column's Range
        Debug.Print Rng.Address

        ' do your stuff with the Rng found per column

    Next Col

End With

End Sub
```